# How to toggle each button separately on multiple li elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I am working on project and my goal is to toggle each individual li element by clicking toggle button.
I managed to do this so far but it's working only on first li element.
Can you help me with this code?

```html
<li id="liEl">Target This element</li>
<button id="Btn">toggle</button>

<li id="liEl" >Target This element</li>
<button id="Btn">toggle</button>

<li id="liEl" >Target This element</li>
<button id="Btn">toggle</button>
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-thickness: 0.2rem;
  text-decoration-color:red;
}
```

```
Btn= document.getElementById("Btn");
liEl= document.getElementById("liEl");

const toggleDoneClass = () => {

  liEl.classList.toggle('done');
};

Btn.addEventListener('click', toggleDoneClass);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs should be unique in a page so maybe switch those to classes.

If you want the buttons you should add them *within* the list item elements.

You can attach one listener to the `<ul>` element and have that catch events from its children as they "bubble up" the DOM. (This is known as [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/).)

When a click event is fired you can retrieve the specific element that was clicked with [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), check that it's a button element, find the [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) list item element to that button, and then toggle its class.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', toggleDoneClass);

function toggleDoneClass(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    e.target.closest('li').classList.toggle('done');
  }
}
```

```css
.done { text-decoration: line-through; text-decoration-thickness: 0.2rem; text-decoration-color:red; }
li button { margin-left: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="liEl">
    Target This element
    <button type="button">Toggle</button>
  </li>
  <li class="liEl">
    Target This element
    <button type="button">Toggle</button>
  </li>
  <li class="liEl">
    Target This element
    <button type="button">Toggle</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But, ultimately, you don't really need the buttons.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', toggleDoneClass);

function toggleDoneClass(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('li')) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('done');
  }
}
```

```css
.done { text-decoration: line-through; text-decoration-thickness: 0.2rem; text-decoration-color:red; }
li:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="liEl">Target This element</li>
  <li class="liEl">Target This element</li>
  <li class="liEl">Target This element</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

id attribute must be unique.
you can use class instead of that.

**HTML**

```
<li class="list_element">Target This element</li>
<button class="btn">toggle</button>

<li class="list_element" >Target This element</li>
<button class="btn">toggle</button>

<li class="list_element" >Target This element</li>
<button class="btn">toggle</button>
```

You must select all buttons and then add Event Listener to each one by a loop.

**Javascript**

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
         // Previous is li because li is before button
         btns[i].previousElementSibling.classList.toggle("done");
    });
}
```

Now this is Working.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the same ids to all the buttons and li instead of id use class names

```
btns= document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
```

it will select all the classes which contain buttons

```
for(let index = 0;index < btns.length; index++){
   btns[index].onclick = (evt) =>{
  evt.target.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle("done")
    }
}
```

looping all the classes on which you will click it will take that element and then get their previous child which is li and toggle class on that

```js
btns= document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for(let index = 0;index < btns.length; index++){
   btns[index].onclick = (evt) =>{
  evt.target.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle("done")
    }
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-thickness: 0.2rem;
  text-decoration-color:red;
}
```

```html
<li id="" >Target This element</li>
<button  class="btn">toggle</button>

<li id="" >Target This element</li>
<button  class="btn">toggle</button>

<li id="lEl" >Target This element</li>
<button  class="btn">toggle</button>
```